# Is there any way i can optimize the code for Logistic Regression model

Tags: python

1. 

```
X_train = np.asarray(X_train)
    y_train = np.asarray(y_train)
    X_test = np.asarray(X_test)
    y_test = np.asarray(y_test)
    X_val = np.asarray(X_valid)
    y_val = np.asarray(y_valid)
```

3. 

```
import cv2
    X_train_full = []
        X_test_full = [] 
        X_valid_full = []
        for i in X_train:
            res = cv2.resize(i, dsize=(28, 28), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
            X_train_full.append(res)
            
        for i in X_test:
            res = cv2.resize(i, dsize=(28, 28), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
            X_test_full.append(res)
            
        for i in X_val:
            res = cv2.resize(i, dsize=(28, 28), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
            X_valid_full.append(res)

4. 

X_train_full = np.asarray(X_train_full)
    X_test_full = np.asarray(X_test_full)
    X_valid_full = np.asarray(X_valid_full)
    
5. 

from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
    from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
    
    scaler = StandardScaler()
    
    scaler.fit(X_train_full)
    
    X_train_full = scaler.transform(X_train_full)
    X_test_full = scaler.transform(X_test_full)


6. 

from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
    models = list()
    accuracy = list()
    save = 'svm/'
    name = 'svm'
    for i in range(len(dataset)):
        name = 'model'+str(i)
        data = dataset[i]
        X_train = data[0][0]
        y_train = data[0][1]
        X_test = data[1][0]
        y_test = data[1][1]
        
        logisticRegr = LogisticRegression(solver='lbfgs',multi_class='multinomial')
        logisticRegr.fit(X_train,y_train)
        
        prediction = logisticRegr.predict(X_test)
        accuracy.append(accuracy_score(y_test,prediction))
        print('Accuracy ',str(i),': ',accuracy_score(y_test,prediction))

7. 

logisticRegr = LogisticRegression(solver='lbfgs',multi_class='multinomial')
    logisticRegr.fit(X_train,y_train)
    
    predictions = logisticRegr.predict(X_test)
```

After i run the StandardScaler() part in my jupyter/colab, it crashed bcuz the memory overallocated.
 Is there way i can fix the code for the LogisticRegression Model? 
At first , i load the datasets consist of 161 folders with 500 data in each folder
Then, i run a random() to shuffle the data among all of them.
and create a X_train_full to resize the image and save them in
Then i perform the StandardScaler on my latest X_train_full but it crashed, 
 Is there any solution since i have already resize my image dimension to 28,28 from 192,256.[image: shape of the nparray size]

Answer (score 1):

Well, you have a lot of data and simultaneously loading that data and performing operations on them is leading to memory crash.

In such a scenario, we should use dataset pipelines like tensorflow dataset `tf.data.Dataset` . This will load your data in batches rather than whole and is very memory efficient.

If you are using pytorch, then you can use `torch.utils.data.DataLoader` which is also a data loader.

For more information visit

`Tensorflow`
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset

`Pytorch`
https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.DataLoader